# App installation failed with message: Failed to commit install session

Tags: android, android-studio

Yesterday my app was running perfect from Android Studio. But today when I upgraded to **Android Studio 3.4 Canary 6**, I started getting the following error message continuously:

> Installation failed with message Failed to commit install session
>   1249295977 with command cmd package install-commit 1249295977.
>
> It is
>   possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing
>   version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

Error dialog:

[image: Application installation failed]

When I click OK and then re-Run, I get this error message.

> Session 'app':Error Installing APKs

I tried to manually delete the app, but it's already deleted from my phone. Restarting Android Studio, invalidating caches and rebuilding are not working either.

Comment: See the log, in `Run` bottom left side, and try to resolved this.

Comment: Which device are you installing your app?

Comment: @SaikrishnaRajaraman S7 Edge

Comment: do you have another version of the app installed already? perhaps a alpha/beta version and you are now trying to install a Debug APK / development version ?

Comment: @jesses.co.tt As I said above "I tried to manually delete the app, but it's already deleted from my phone". I'm already try to uninstall the app before hit Run button, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 12):

check 4 ways:

**way 1:** turn off Instant Run

> File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check
>   (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)

**way 2:** Go to Build --> Clean Project and Run again

**way 3:** For those who use Xiaomi phones, follow these steps:

```
Settings-> Additional Settings-> Developer opetions

Turn off MIUI Optimization and reboot your phone

Last Disable verify app over USB
```

**way 4:** Run Invalidate caches/restart in android studio

```
Choose the File option in windows and preference in mac
Select Invalidate caches/restart.
Click Invalidate and restart.
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I disable Instant Run from *Setting-> Build, Execution, Deployment ->Instant Run*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was not enough space on the cellphone. I've got a clear error message when I tried to install the app manually via ADB:

```
$ ./gradlew installDebug

> Task :app:installDebug
07:23:47 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
07:23:47 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'R58M45K5MPZ' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:23:47 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'SM-A205F - 9' for app:debug
07:23:47 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'R58M45K5MPZ'
07:23:47 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'R58M45K5MPZ'
07:23:47 D/ddms: Reading file permision of /home/egslava/temp/android-projects/RedditTestFeed/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk as: rw-rw-r--
07:23:48 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
07:23:56 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'R58M45K5MPZ' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:23:56 V/ddms: execute: returning
07:23:56 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
07:23:56 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'R58M45K5MPZ' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:23:56 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

Most easy way to solve this is, wipe data of your emulator and run project again.